# Displaying php result in HTML using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to display the result of my php in different `<div>`-s. My plan is that I make a query in my php and display the result in JSON format. Due to the JSON format my result can be displaying in different `<div>`. **How can I reach that for example the `"name"` can be displayed between  `<div>` tags?**

**The example result of php:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "example1",
        "title": "example2"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "example1",
        "title": "example2"
    }
]
```

**The attempt:**

```
 <div class="result"></div>

 <script>
 $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'foo.php',
    data:'json',
    success: function(data){
            $('.result').html(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.html(data[0].name)`... Do you know how to access JSON data?

Comment: `$('.result').append('<div>' + data[0].name + '</div>')` - it add div with name of first result to div with result class.

Comment: `success: function(data){
    var newhtml = ''; 
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        newhtml +='<div>'+ item.name +'</div>';
    });
    $('.result').html(newhtml);
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi try parsing the returned data into a JSON object :

```
<div class="result"></div>

 <script>
 $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'foo.php',
    data:'json',
    success: function(data){

            // added JSON parse
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

            // iterate through every object
            $.each(jsonData, function(index, element) {

                 // do what you want with each JSON object
                 $('.result').append('<div>' + element.name + '</div>');

            });                
    }
});
</script>
```

// PS code is untested.
// Regards

Answer (score 2):

Do it like below:-

```
success: function(data){
    var newhtml = ''; //newly created string variable
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {//iterate over json data
        newhtml +='<div>'+ item.name +'</div>'; // get name and wrapped inside div and append it to newly created string variable
    });
    $('.result').html(newhtml); // put value of newly created div into result element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  var id = $("<div></div>").html(data[i].id);
  var name = $("<div></div>").html(data[i].name);
   var title = $("<div></div>").html(data[i].title);

  $('.result').append(id).append(name).append(title);
}
```